# Match arms have incompatible types when handling an Err with a panic

Tags: rust

I have this little piece of code that I want to use to log the error and panic if the function fails but I cant seem to get it to work because I'm getting the "match arms have incompatible types..." error.

I get that I'm supposed to provide these values, but is there a way to not do that since we are panicking anyway?

Or maybe there is an alternative way? I'm trying to log an error and using `.expect` only panics but does not produce a suitable log or does not do any of the other instrumentation we need.

```rust
// this is in my instrumentation crate
pub fn handle_error(panic_msg: &str, process: &str, status: &str, error: Box<dyn Error>) {
    event!(Level::ERROR, process=process, status=status, error);
    panic!("{}", panic_msg);
}
```

```rust
fn main() {
   let (val1, val2, val3) = match function_call(user_id).await {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(e) => instrumentation::handle_error("panic", "proc", "failed", Box::new((e))),
    };
}
```

Comment: What should `(val1, val2, val3)` be when you encounter `Err` variant? In `Ok(x)` case you return `x` from match expression, but in `Err` you return the return value of `instrumentation::handle_error` which is `()`. Since those are different types, rust correctly tells you about this error.

Comment: In this case just empty, but I understand rust does not have null values correct? Could I return an empty value somehow or provide it the value it needs before panicking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to tell your consumers that `instrumentation::handle_error` will never return you can express that by telling that it return type is `!` (known as [never](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html) type). This type can be coerced to any other type. Just change `hande_error` to:

```rust
pub fn handle_error(
    panic_msg: &str,
    process: &str,
    status: &str,
    error: Box<dyn Error>,
) -> ! {
    event!(Level::ERROR, process=process, status=status, error);
    panic!("{}", panic_msg)
}
```

Panicking is a form of diverging in Rust and that is represented in the type system as returning the "never" type, spelled as `!` (and so are infinite loops). This will make your match statement compile, you will not have to change anything there.

Answer (score 4):

You simply have to tell the compiler that the `handle_error()` function will never return.
Its return type should then be specified as `-> !`.

Then the compiler won't try to ensure both branches of the `match` statement have the same type.

This situation (with `match` involved) is described in [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#the-never-type-that-never-returns).

```rust
fn try_but_fail(
) -> std::result::Result<(i32, i32, i32), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Err("Sorry")?
}

fn handle_error(error: Box<dyn std::error::Error>) -> ! {
    panic!("ERROR: {:?}", error);
}

fn main() {
    let (val1, val2, val3) = match try_but_fail() {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(e) => handle_error(e),
    };
    println!("{} {} {}", val1, val2, val3);
}
/*
$ cargo run 
thread 'main' panicked at 'ERROR: "Sorry"', src/main.rs:7:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

…or you can refactor `main` and remove the `match`:

```
fn main() {
   let rslt = function_call(user_id).await;
   let Ok(x) = rslt else {
        instrumentation::handle_error("panic", "proc", "failed", Box::new((rslt.err().unwrap())));
   }
   // do something with x here…
}
```